# Excel Dynamic sumproduct

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a vector (range of values) of the form (a_11,..,a_1n,...,a_m1...,a_mn) for m and n which are input from another sheet and a vector of probabilities (p_1,...,p_n). In another sheet I now have different subsets of 1,..,m as input so for example I have the string "1,3,4". I would now like to calculate for this string

```
a_11*a_31*a_41*p_1+a_12*a_32*a_42*p_2+...+a_1n* a_3n* a_4n*p_n
```

(basically the sumproduct of the vectors (a_11,...,a_1n), (a_31,...,a_3n), (a_41,...,a_4n) and (p_1,...,p_n)

As the string "1,3,4" differs each time (also in length) I would like to do this dynamically but without using VBA. I have already succeeded doing it in VBA by means of a double loop but I want to use the solver so I want to implement it in a sheet refering to the entries.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping it simple and just copying across the a<sub>i,j</sub> to another sheet, setting them to one for rows you don't want to be in the multiplication. So if your Sheet1 looked like this

[image]

Use this formula in Sheet2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&ROWS(A$2:A2)&",",","&$E$2&",")),Sheet1!A2,1)
```

and just do the multiplications using PRODUCT on each column so you get

[image]

The products may also be calculated in a single formula as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(6,OFFSET(A1,1,COLUMN(A2:C5)-COLUMN(A:A),ROWS(A2:C5),1)),Sheet1!A8:C8)
```

if preferred.